# Building OpenCV 2.2 html documentation

Tags: opencv

I've followed the directions here to build html documentation https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/doc/README.txt (actually my local copy that came with OpenCV 2.2, but they are the same), but I get this error after running sh buildall:

```
parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "latex.py", line 714, in <module>
fulldoc = latexparser(sys.argv[1])
File "/home/user/OpenCV-2.2.0/doc/latex2sphinx/latexparser.py", line 114, in latexparser
tokens = tokenize(filename)
File "/home/user/OpenCV-2.2.0/doc/latex2sphinx/latexparser.py", line 106, in tokenize
pickle.dump(r, open(cache_filename, 'w'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'parse-cache/c83e178b805f6b01ff8d55cda4bd4a29'
```

The pdf file built fine but I prefer html.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by simply doing "mkdir parse-cache" in the opencv/doc/latex2sphinx directory.